# Depending on the following, the following information is displayed, otherwise it will not be displayed

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
  condition is: Today value is more than yesterday and yesterday more than the day before if this happened show else not show

    select * from mytable where

    all records 2018-01-03   2018-01-02   2018-01-01
                    |      >     |      >     |
                  value        value        value
    in last 3 day and Every day more than the day before
(Today is more than yesterday and yesterday more than the day before if this happened show else not show)

    +-----------------------------------+
        name        date        value   
        -----------------------------   
        apple   2018-01-03      1000     
        lg      2018-01-03      2000
        sony    2018-01-03      2000
        bmw     2018-01-03      3000
        apple   2018-01-02      2000
        lg      2018-01-02      1000
        sony    2018-01-02      2500
        bmw     2018-01-02      2000
        apple   2018-01-01      500
        lg      2018-01-01      500
        sony    2018-01-01      3000
        bmw     2018-01-01      1000

    +-----------------------------------+

    I need the following result:

    +-----------------------------------+
        name        date        value   
        -----------------------------        
        lg      2018-01-03      2000
        bmw     2018-01-03      3000
        lg      2018-01-02      1000
        bmw     2018-01-02      2000
        lg      2018-01-01      500
        bmw     2018-01-01      1000

    +-----------------------------------+

    Thanks all
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where 
(date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-03')
 AND 
(name = 'lg' AND name = 'bmw')
```

Comment: and Every day more than the day before if ok show else not show

Comment: i cant understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: cond => and Today is more than yesterday and yesterday more than the day before if this happened show else not show

Answer (score 0):

```
select name
       ,date
       ,value
from 
 (select t1.name as name
        ,t1.date as date
        ,t1. value as value
        ,t2.value as date_minus_1_value
        ,t3.value as date_minus_2_value
  from mytable t1
  inner join mytable t2
  on t1.name = t2.name and t1.date = date_add(t2.date,interval -1 day)
  inner join mytable t3
  on t1.name = t3.name and t1.date = date_add(t3.date,interval -2 day)
  )
where (value > date_minus_1_value and date_minus_1_value > 
date_minus_2_value)
```

Comment: and Every day more than the day before if ok show else not show

Comment: Check this then

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE mytable.date> DATEADD(dd,-3,GETDATE())
```

Comment: this is not mysql tho

Comment: and Every day more than the day before if ok show else not show

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.